# Apache Commons CLI 1.3.1: Option coming after another option with multiple arguments is consumed as ARGUMENT

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm using Apache Commons CLI 1.3.1 to process some options and some of the options can take one to unlimited number arguments. A trivia example with two options would be like this

```
usage: myProgram -optionX <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> < ... > [-optionY]
-optionX <arg1> <arg2> <arg3> < ... >   optionX takes one to unlimited
                                        number of arguments.
-optionY                                optionY is optional
```

What I found is that the second option `optionY` is always recognized as an **ARGUMENT** of the `optionX` instead of being recognized as an **OPTION** by itself. That means if you type
`myProgram -optionX arg1 arg2 -optionY` in the command line, you will get three arguments (`arg1`, `arg2`, and `-optionY`) associated with `optionX`.

Here is the code that anyone can use to reproduce the problem.

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;

public class TestCli {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Option optObj1 = Option.builder("optionX")
                            .argName("arg1> <arg2> <arg3> < ... ")
                            .desc("optionX takes one to unlimited number of arguments.")
                            .required()
                            .hasArgs()
                            .build();

    Option optObj2 = new Option("optionY", "optionY is optional");

    Options optsList = new Options();
    optsList.addOption(optObj1);
    optsList.addOption(optObj2);

    CommandLineParser commandLineParser = new DefaultParser();

    try {

        CommandLine cmd = commandLineParser.parse(optsList, new String[]{"-optionX", "arg1", "arg2", "-optionY"});

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("argument list of optionX: ");
        for (String argName : cmd.getOptionValues(optObj1.getOpt())) {
            System.out.println("arg: " + argName);
        }

        System.out.println("--------------------------");
        System.out.println("value of optionY: " + cmd.hasOption(optObj2.getOpt()));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Unexcepted option: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

This is the output you'll see.

```
--------------------------
argument list of optionX: 
arg: arg1
arg: arg2
arg: -optionY
--------------------------
value of optionY: false
```

Do I miss something here?

Any suggestion will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are putting the long name in the short name of the option.

When you use `Option optObj1 = Option.builder("optionX")....` or `new Option("optionY", "optionY is optional")`, you're setting the short name of the option, which is supposed to be only 1 character long.

That work well until you have a multi arguments option. In this case, the parser cannot find "o" (the first letter of your option) in his short option list and you don't have a long name set, so the parser determines that -optionY is just another argument for -optionX.

**To solve your problem, just set the long option name of your option and it should work alright.**

**Example**

```
Option.builder("x").longOpt("optionX")....

Option optObj2 = new Option("y", "optionY", hasArgs, "optionY is optional");
```

Comment: Your second option probably should not have the same short value as the first one.